# Losing database connection when changing project target framework

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

As in title I'm having problem with my VB project when I change its .NET Framework from 4.5.1 in which I have application written to v4 which is supported on windowsXP. When I make the change and try to compile my program database could not be found. Should I make any extra changes in project properties or why database could not be found?

Thank you for help!

Comment: I've tried few more things on project properties and changed target CPU to x86 and now it works. I'm on 64Bit machine and obviously this has something to do with jet.Oledb.4.0 since it's not working on my machine when compiling project with AnyCPU settings.

Answer (score 0):

The Jet engine is not supported on 64bit machines.  I know it is crazy but it's true.  Not sure what MS Access uses on 64Bit, must be something else.

[Jet on 64Bit](https://www.google.com/#q=jet+64bit)

Some places say it's not going to be supported, others say it is part of Office 2010 install and you can download a seperate driver.

I ran into this when deploying a web app to our 64Bit server and just found a way around using MS Access for our report server.  Got luck.